# How to know if mac platform is macOSx64 or macOSaarch64

Tags: java, macos, corretto

I am trying to download JDK from Amazon Corretto https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html. There are 2 download links for macOS (macOSx64 or macOSaarch64) but I am not sure which one should be downloaded. I am using macOS Monterey Version 12.0.1

Comment: Usually, `menubar > about this mac` should show you everything needed

Comment: You need to provide more information on your device. "macOSaarch64" is an Arm processor, whereas "macOSx64" will be an intel processor

Comment: Did you try to google this?

Comment: I did, but I do not find a clear answer.

Comment: @zatef FYI, the inventors of Stack Overflow intended these Questions here to be the top results of a web search. The existence of other sources of info outside Stack Overflow does not disqualify a Question here, as long as the Question is on-topic.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque I dont remember the context around asking the OP to google this. But, yea, you are correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## *About This Mac*

1. From the Apple icon menu, choose `About This Mac`.
2. Look for the item `Chip`.
3. If that item says `M1` or `M2` or `M3`, then you have a Mac with [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon#M_series) based on the ARM architecture. Download your `macOSaarch64` option.
4. If that item says `Intel`, then you have the [x64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) chip architecture. Download your `macOSx64` option.

[[image: screenshot of About This Mac]]

See Apple support page, [*Mac computers with Apple silicon*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/116943).

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following command to get that

```
uname -a
```

Having x64 in there might give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is one of the new M1 or M2 chip computers, then you would use macOSaarch64.

If your computer is an older Intel chip computer, then you would use macOSx64.

You can tell which you have by going to **Apple** menu and then selecting '**About This Mac**' and Look for '**Processor**' or '**Chip**' in the About This Mac window.